# Can socket.io client connect to two different servers/ports?

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

Can socket.io client connect to two different ports on the same server?

Can socket.io client connect to two different server?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Can socket.io client connect to two different ports on the same
>   server?

I assume both machines share same domain. I believe it can use long-polling(websockets, flashsockets, etc also work), even passing along cookie. But I still need to test this on Internet Explorer because that browser never does what I want...

> Can socket.io client connect to two different server?

The big question is if those both machines are on different domains. If on same domain it will work just fine even passing along cookie(s). If they are on different domains then on some browser we fall-back to json-p transport(worst transport imaginable), but it will work. Unfortunately then the cookie is not passed along, because of same origin policy. Right now I am toying to get around this cookie restriction(hard problem)...

Answer (score 25):

**Sure:**

```
var io1 = require('socket.io').listen(8001);

io1.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
});


var io2 = require('socket.io').listen(8002);

io2.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.emit('flash', { hello: 'world' });
});
```

Perhaps this is an interesting read: (from [**github**](https://github.com/LearnBoost/Socket.IO/wiki/Migrating-0.6-to-0.7))

```
// connect at the same host / port as your website
var socket = io.connect();

// different port or host
var socket = io.connect('http://url.com');

// secure
var socket = io.connect('https://localhost');
```